# Скруглить углы у видео с ютуба

Tags: html, css, youtube, youtube-api

Как можно победить этот момент.
Загружаю видео с ютуба на сайт, для родительского элемента задаю `border-radius`, сразу, при загрузке страницы всё нормально, углы скруглены, но после запуска видео оно вылазит за пределы родительского блока.

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '160',
        width: '340',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        playerVars: {
            rel: 0,
            controls: 0,
            showinfo: 0
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.player{
  border-radius: 15px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="player" id="player"></div>
```

Comment: overflow: hidden обертке давали?

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис давал, без толку, не работало, пока не добавил `webkit-mask-image` и `webkit-transform` как в ответе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё решилось, благодаря этому парню 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811719/adding-border-radius-for-embedded-youtube-video/21766174#21766174

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '160',
        width: '340',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        playerVars: {
            rel: 0,
            controls: 0,
            showinfo: 0
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.player{
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%); /*ios 7 border-radius-bug */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0.000001deg); /*mac os 10.6 safari 5 border-radius-bug */
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="player" id="player"></div>
```